# Context Free Grammar - Production Rule validation

Tags: grammar

I need help about this problem.

Given the following production rules, which ones are not valid in CFG:

1. A -> aaVAa
2. aAs -> Vaa
3. SS -> a
4. S -> ɛ
5. S -> S

Please help me, I need to explain if its valid or not. Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 1):

The second and the third productions. A production only can be performed on a single non terminal symbol.